# Переключение закладок броузера

Tags: javascript

Возможно ли программно переключать закладки броузера ?

Answer (score 1):

Да, мышкой. Еще шоткаты есть для разных браузеров ;)

---

То, что корректируете вопрос - это хорошо, но суть от этого не меняется. Как бы вы себя чувствовали, если бы находились на одной закладке, а кто-то бы начал переключать закладки у вас? Фиговенько. Именно поэтому за вас беспокоились и создали политику безопасности.